# returning an Array of tuples using map on an Array in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, type-conversion, typeerror

I have an Array `const x:number[] = [1,2,3,4,5]` and I'm trying to obtain an array of tuples containing the original value in `x` and a value obtained by mapping a function on it.
My attempt was something like this

```
pos = x.map(xi => (
    [xi, 3*xi]
))
```

This returns `pos` as of type `number[][]` but I want a `[number, number]` as result.
Do you know how to fix this code?

Comment: `[xi, 3*xi] as const` will do the job. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-tuple-types: array literals with const assertions will be inferred with readonly tuple types.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mAJ4ZW) work for you? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Both ways returned the wanted result so upvote to both of you. In my case i had to put the result in a Vector2 object and only @jcalz solution worked for me later in the code. If you want put the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, TypeScript will see an [array literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#array_literals) like `[xi, 3 * xi]` and infer its type to be an unordered [array type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#arrays) of arbitrary length like `number[]`, and not a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) like `[number, number]`.  That's often what people want, since arrays are more common than tuples.  When such inference isn't suitable, you'll need to do something to ask the compiler to do something else.

There are a number of ways to do this.  If you explicitly want `[number, number]`, then the most straightforward approach is to manually specify the `U` type argument for the [`Array.prototype.map` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) which is [declared like](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/3fab5fff347fb7192bdf182668f513eb59e48024/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L1424):

```
interface Array<T> {
    map<U>(cb: (v: T, i: number, a: T[]) => U, thisArg?: any): U[];
}
```

Like this:

```
const x: number[] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const pos = x.map<[number, number]>(xi => (
   [xi, 3 * xi]
));
// const pos: [number, number][]
```

But in general, you can either manually [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) the variable to which you're assigning the literal:

```
const pos = x.map(xi => {
   const ret: [number, number] = [xi, 3 * xi];
   return ret;
});
// const pos: [number, number][]
```

or you could use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to get the compiler to change its inference algorithm to prefer [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) and [`readonly` tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-tuple-types):

```
const pos = x.map(xi => [xi, 3 * xi] as const);
// const pos: (readonly [number, number])[]
```

The type `readonly [number, number]` is not identical to `[number, number]`, but depending on your use case it might suffice.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.2#code/MYewdgzgLgBAHgLhmArgWwEYFMBOBtAXRgF4Y8BGAGhgCZqBmagFmoFYCBuAKFElgAcQEEvAB0aAIb8APHlSZc1edhwEAfAAo4ASxJqYGrjGN4dDGACp42glwCUd7gHonMXtBiCISOehVK-XAJCLh5wDy8aEThxKS1dYn0AbyNjd1gcLCgfZUVkQNURU21zKx1OVJhMqBQcMCqs7gBfRy4XN3CBIRocgoCFVRCwvk8hemjY-ni9MjMYcbKbGAlhdNb29NGIeiQNTIkAE3AAGwBPMlycfpUCO0IgA)